# What is the command for the shortcut _?

Tags: keyboard

I was trying to look up what _? does but I couldn't find anything in the documentation and it's hard to look up symbolic strings because most search engines use these symbols internally.

Comment: My favorite cheat-sheet is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html).  Look under Patterns.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate. Please see specifically: [(25616)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_?` is not a single operator.  `_` and `?` are two separate things:

`_` is [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html), relatively easily found using the documentation centre.

`?` is [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html), a bit harder to find.

Comment: Would you object to my closing this as a duplicate of [(18393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it should be closed.